# Nginx logrotate not working on Amazon Server

Tags: ubuntu, logging, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am new to server side.I had installed Nginx on my server (Amazon EC2 32 bit instance)to run my Ruby on Rails application.I have written the below configuration for my nginx logrotate.

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 12
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi; \
    endscript
    postrotate
        [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
    endscript
}
```

But the problem is that in spite of the rotation interval kept as daily..there was a file (nginx access log)which was generated at around 4.5 Gb.I dont know why this is happening and can anyone suggest to me what i can do to avoid this.Can someone Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the logrotate setup installed with the Nginx package from repositories? It works like a charm:

```
/var/log/nginx/*log {
    create 0644 nginx nginx
    daily
    rotate 10
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/nginx reopen_logs
    endscript
}
```

Also, verify the user and prerotate scripts. You are using www-data and http-prerotate script, which are Apache Server specific.

And finally, why don't you just use the built-in reopen_logs method in the Nginx init script? The signal you are using may change over time in future Nginx releases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something but the most obvious thing that your configuration doesn't have is the actual `size` declaration. After at what point should the logs be rotated and compressed?

> **size** 
>                 Log files are rotated when they grow bigger then size bytes.  If
>                 size  is  followed by M, the size if assumed to be in megabytes.
>                 If the k is used, the size is in kilobytes. So  size  100,  size
>                 100k, and size 100M are all valid.

Also to note, if you're using nginx, I think you can skip the `postrotate` and just use `copytruncate`:

> **copytruncate**
>                 Truncate  the  original log file in place after creating a copy,
>                 instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new
>                 one,  It  can be used when some program can not be told to close
>                 its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending)  to  the
>                 previous log file forever.

Documentation: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html